# Kivy - My ScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: android, python, scroll, kivy, kivy-language

I'm having problems in my Python application with Kivy library. In particular I'm trying to create a scrollable list of elements in a TabbedPanelItem, but I don't know why my list doesn't scroll.

Here is my kv file:

```
#:import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager
ScreenManagement:
     transition: sm.FadeTransition()
     SecondScreen:

<SecondScreen>:
    tabba: tabba
    name: 'second'
    FloatLayout:
        background_color: (255, 255, 255, 1.0)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 0.10
            pos_hint: {'top': 1.0}
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0.98, 0.4, 0, 1.0)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Label:
                text: 'MyApp'
                font_size: 30
                size: self.texture_size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 0.90
            Tabba:
                id: tabba

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 0.10
            pos_hint: {'bottom': 1.0}
            Button:
                background_color: (80, 1, 0, 1.0)
                text: 'Do nop'
                font_size: 25


<Tabba>:
    do_default_tab: False
    background_color: (255, 255, 255, 1.0)

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'First_Tab'
        Tabs:

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Second_Tab'
        Tabs:

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Third_Tab'
        Tabs:


<Tabs>:
    grid: grid
    ScrollView:
        scroll_timeout: 250
        scroll_distance: 20
        do_scroll_y: True
        do_scroll_x: False
        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            cols: 1
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            Label:
                text:'scroll'
                color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
            Label:
                text:'scroll'
                color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
        Label:
            text:'scroll'
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
```

And here my .py code:

```
__author__ = 'drakenden'

__version__ = '0.1'

import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class Tabs(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Tabs, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Tabba(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("layout2.kv")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation


MyApp().run()
```

Where/What am I doing wrong?

(Comments and suggests for UI improvements are also accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Myself haven't used kivy for a while but if I remember exacly:
Because layout within ScrollView should be BIGGER than scroll view
ex ScrollView width: 1000px, GridView 1100px. 
So it will be possible to scroll it by 100px

Comment: So,do you suggest to set the inner layout's height less than ScrollView?

Comment: Drakenden no it should be bigger :)

Comment: Yes, at the end I resolved setting ScrollView height bigger than GridView. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Grid Layout should have a defined height to scroll inside scroll view

```
ScrollView:
        scroll_timeout: 250
        scroll_distance: 20
        do_scroll_y: True
        do_scroll_x: False

        GridLayout:
            id: grid
            cols: 1
            height: self.minimum_height # this helps scroll allow scroll if grid layout height becomes more than scrollview.
```